# Testing A function

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I need to write a unit test for a function. I have no idea about testing and the examples I have seen are more maths oriented so I can not understand how to write a test for this funtion. Can Anyone please help me write a unit test for this function:

```
public static void CreateUser(
    int userId, 
    string name, 
    System.DateTime createdAt, 
    string createdBy, 
    System.DateTime modifiedAt, 
    string modifiedBy, 
    string address, 
    string city, 
    string province, 
    string country, 
    string postcode, 
    string phone)
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDbContext _usermain = new UserDbContext())
        {
            User newuser = new User()
            {
                UserId = userId,
                Name = name,
                CreatedAt = createdAt,
                CreatedBy = createdBy,
                ModifiedBy = modifiedBy,
                ModifiedAt = modifiedAt,
                Address = address,
                City = city
            };
            _usermain.Users.Add(newuser);
            _usermain.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = string.Format("Error in Creating User", ex.Message);
        throw new Exception(error, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method, the way it's currently written, is *not* unit testable. Unit tests should not rely on any external resources (including databases), as they need to be repeatable without changing any background data. In your case since you're creating a database context within the method itself, you won't have any control over how it gets created for a unit test. You'll have to somehow [inject that dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to the method so you can pass in a mocked (read: fake) instance when testing it.

Comment: Unit testing databases is always tricky; you need to mock the database context. There are a few good blog posts on this

Comment: which dependency?

Comment: Dependency on `UserDbContext`.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should be written to validate the *behavior* of a function.  In your case, your function is taking in input and updating a database.  Writing a unit test will be difficult since databases are very hard to mock.  You essentially would need to figure out a way to mock the `UserDbContext`, pass inputs to the function, and verify that the database is updated properly.

I would suggest that a **unit test is not appropriate for this function**.  Its sole purpose is to mutate an external environment that you cannot easily mock.  Some changes that *would* make it *easier* to test are:

- inject the context instead of creating a new one (so you can pass in a mock).  That's probably more trouble than it's worth.
- Making it two functions - one to create a `User` and one to take the `User` and insert it into the database. (In that case I would unit test the first method but not the second).  If you already *have* a unit test for the `User` constructor then the separation and unit test are not needed.

As a side note, catching any exception and throwing a *new* generic exception does not add value.  In fact it *removes* value since you lose or hide the following information:

- The original stack trace
- The error message
- The type of exception.

All of these are buried in the `InnerException` when you throw a new exception.  Just take out the try/catch block and let the original exception bubble up if you're not going to do anything with it.

Comment: So I removed the try/catch and then wrote a test

Comment: [TestMethod]
       public void CreateUser_Test()
       { UserRepository.DeleteAllUser();
           List<User> user = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();
           //Assert.IsNotNull(reportuser);
           Assert.AreEqual(0, user.Count);
           var item = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();
           foreach (var i in item)
           {     UserRepository.CreateUser(i.UserId, "Ali", DateTime.Now, "Saniya", DateTime.Now, "Saniya", "Pak",  "Rwp", "Punjab", "Pakistan", "46000", "03361054");  }
  var allUser = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();
  Assert.AreEqual(allUser.Count(), item.Count()); }

Comment: But now I am having an exception with test failing  System.Data.Core.MetaDataExceptions: Unable to load the specified metadata resource        @D Stanley

Comment: @Saniya Do you have the appropriate configuration for your unit test project?  Specifically the connection string for the data model?

Comment: No - `item` is the list of items in the DB, but you've deletes all of them, so it will be an empty collection.  Regardless, I think cleaning out the repository just to test that your add logic works in not a good "unit test".  You still have a dependency on the database and rick deleting data that should not be deleted.

Comment: @DStanley So you are saying that deleting the data is not a good approach

Comment: @Saniya Not in my opinion.  Essentially all you're testing is the `User` constructor and the `Add` functionality of the context.  The former can easily be tested on its own and the latter is not something you can change.

Comment: @DStanley I got your point. But i am still getting those metadata resource error although i have the correct connection string

Comment: When I search for that error message the results I get are all related to dependencies and/or configuration, neither of which can be diagnosed from a code sample.  Do you have the project that contains the EDMX as a dependency of the unit test project?

Comment: @DStanley I found the issue. Thank you so much for your help :)